# Anaconda root prefix is not correct

Tags: python, anaconda

When I launch the Anaconda prompt I get this[image]

but the correct location is the following

[image]

How can I change this? 
Thank you!

Comment: I'd say that *is* the correct default directory for a user login named "VILLAFADE".  You don't want to put your programs in Anaconda's installation directory.  That's subject to getting erased should you need to reinstall Anaconda.  Per-user files should be somewhere under C:\Users\<login name>.  Files shared between two different logins usually belong somewhere under C:\Users\Public\Documents

Comment: I have problems the ñ character, so I install Anaconda in another folder, but I have this error. Another way to fix this error? Another important thing is that I cannot launch the anaconda navigator

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192